# Should I use a global state or React hook's local state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-state

I have the following code (using React hooks):

```
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);

const [branch, setBranch] = useState<TaskingBranchState | null>(null);
const handleBranchChange = (event: ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: TaskingBranchState | null) => {
    setBranch(newValue);
    setBranchMembers([]);
}
const [branchMembers, setBranchMembers] = useState([]);
const handleBranchMembersChange = (event: ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: any) => {
    setBranchMembers(newValue);
}
```

Somewhere later in the code, I'm doing a `useQuery` to get the `branchMembers`, which is dispatched into my global `state`. If it matters, it looks like this:

```
useQuery(GET_BRANCH_MEMBERS(["id", "name"]), {
    variables: {
        branchId: branch?.branchId
    },
    onCompleted: (data) => {
        if (data !== undefined && data.getBranchMembers !== undefined && data.getBranchMembers !== state.branchMembers) {
            dispatch({
                type: 'DISPATCH_TYPE',
                payload: {
                    branchMembers: data.getBranchMembers
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

where `dispatch` writes the `payload` to a global `state` (the same `state` above in `useContext`).

My questions are:

1. Should I be using `state.branchMembers` (the global value which `useQuery` dispatches to) or simply call `setBranchMembers` and use the local `branchMembers` state defined above?
2. What's the difference?
3. In either case, do I no longer need to define either global state (if answering no to Q1) or no longer need to define anything with `useState` locally (if answering yes to Q1)?

Been messing around with my code for a bit and only just realised I had this confusion. Not too familiar with React hooks tbh, so if it's a fundamentals problem, please help as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you would like to share the `branchMembers` between different components.

Since you are already dispatching `branchMembers` to the global state I assume that you do want to share it. Therefore, you can just go with global state only and remove `useState`

```
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
...
doSomethingWith(state.branchMembers);
...
```

There is NO NEED to write global state data (from context) to local state (from `useState`) in order to use it. You can use data from context right away.

**UPDATE**

If your `branchMembers` depend on `branch` then just go ahead and dispatch the `branchData` along with `branchMembers`. Just remember to write it in the reducer

```
dispatch({
  type: "WRITE_BRANCH_AND_BRANCH_MEMBERS",
  payload: {
    branch: branchId, // or branch or branchData whatever needed
    branchMembers: data.getBranchMembers,
  },
});


// your-reducer.js
function reducer(state, action) {
  ...

  switch (action.type) {
  case "WRITE_BRANCH_AND_BRANCH_MEMBERS": {
    newState = {
      ...state,
      branch: action.payload.branchId,
      branchMembers: action.payload.branchMembers,
    }
    break;
  }

  ...

  }
}
```

Comment: that makes sense, thank you! If I however needed to call the same endpoints for each component but instantiate them differently (e.g. I have dispatched something into state.branchMembers in component A as an array, but when I open component B I require state.branchMembers to be initialised as an empty array), then should I be using local state in that case? Thanks!

Comment: sorry but additionally, if my state is dependent on some other state (e.g. branchMembers dependent on branch), then should I therefore use local state?

Comment: Are you actually storing a function in the context ?

Comment: ***if my state is dependent on some other state*** if the `state` it is shared and is dependent on some `otherState` then `otherState` should also be shared and stored along with the original `state` in the context

Comment: noted about the state dependency! I'll bear that in mind in my production code, this one's just something to test the functionality of my backend :) what do you mean by storing a function in the context? I have a bunch of reducers defined in my Store if that's what you mean, they map the output of the payloads to state